# Flatten / Remove hierarchical column headers

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe which is the result of doing a groupby + aggregate sum:

```
df.groupby(['id', 'category']).agg([pd.Series.sum])

                   supply           stock            
                      sum             sum
id     category                                                               
4      abc            161          -0.094
6      sde            -76           0.150
23     hgv             64          -0.054
1      wcd            -14           0.073 
76     jhf             -8          -0.057
```

Because of the groupby and agg, the column headings are now tuples. How do I change the column headings back into single values, ie: the column headings need to be `supply` and `stock`. I just need to get rid of `sum` from the headings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use sum the "agg function name" won't be created as part of the columns (as a MultiIndex):

```
df.groupby(['id', 'category']).sum()
```

---

To remove them, you can drop the level:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)
```

For example:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
     supply     stock
        sum       sum
0  0.501176  0.482497
1  0.442689  0.008664
2  0.885112  0.512066
3  0.724619  0.418720

In [12]: df.columns.droplevel(1)
Out[12]: Index(['supply', 'stock'], dtype='object')

In [13]: df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
     supply     stock
0  0.501176  0.482497
1  0.442689  0.008664
2  0.885112  0.512066
3  0.724619  0.418720
```

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly set the `columns` attribute to whatever you'd like it to be. For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4, 2)),
...                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['supply', 'stock'],
                                                        ['sum', 'sum']]))
>>> df
     supply     stock
        sum       sum
0  0.170950  0.314759
1  0.632121  0.147884
2  0.955682  0.127857
3  0.776764  0.318614

>>> df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
>>> df
     supply     stock
0  0.170950  0.314759
1  0.632121  0.147884
2  0.955682  0.127857
3  0.776764  0.318614
```